# How can I make my immutable binary search-tree generic in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, binary-search-tree

I am newcomer to Scala. I'm trying to develop my own immutable binary search tree.

Firstly, I developed a binary search tree that takes `Int` on its nodes. After that , I decided to develop generic binary search tree.

When I compiled these codes , I took these error message from terminal.

```
trait GenericBST[+T] {

    def add[TT >: T](x: T): GenericBST[TT] = this match {
        case Empty => Branch(x, Empty, Empty)
        case Branch(d, l, r) => 
          if(d > x) Branch(d, l.add(x), r) 
          else if(d < x) Branch(d, l, r.add(x)) 
          else this   
    }
}

case class Branch[+T](x: T, left: GenericBST[T], right: GenericBST[T]) extends GenericBST[T]
case object Empty extends GenericBST[Nothing]
```

> error: value < is not member of type paramater T.

The error is sensible, how can I fix it?

Don't forget I am newcomer for Scala, so please explain this in detail for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` represents any type, but in order to use `>` and `<` you need a type for which ordering makes sense.

In scala words, it means to you have to put a bound of the type `T`, restricting it to all `T` for which an `Ordering[T]` exists. You can use a context bound, or equivalently require an implicit `ord` of type `Ordering[TT]`.

```
trait GenericBST[+A] {
  def add[B >: A](x: B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): GenericBST[B] = {
    import ord.mkOrderingOps
    this match {
      case Empty => Branch(x, Empty, Empty)
      case Branch(e, l, r) =>
        if (e > x) Branch(e, l.add(x), r)
        else if (e < x) Branch(e, l, r.add(x))
        else this
    }
  }
}

case class Branch[+A](x: A, left: GenericBST[A], right: GenericBST[A]) extends GenericBST[A]
case object Empty extends GenericBST[Nothing]
```

Importing `ord.mkOrderingOps` allows for the syntax

```
e > x
```

instead of

```
ord.gt(e, x)
```

---

You could also use a context bound directly, but it would require some extra work to get the implicit `ord` in scope (and it's arguably less readable):

```
def add[B >: A : Ordering](x: B): GenericBST[B] = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[B]]
  import ord.mkOrderingOps
  ...
}
```

---

Absolutely not relevant, but you might be wondering why I used `A` and `B` in my example, as opposed to `T` and `TT`. According to the [official style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html):

> For simple type parameters, a single upper-case letter (from the English alphabet) should be used, starting with `A` (this is different than the Java convention of starting with `T`)

Comment: That's why my solution wasn't working. `x` was supposed to be of type `TT` :)

Comment: First of all , thanks for your answer. I think my fault is I thought that I can create BST which has Any type ,there exist String,Int etc., and I can compare them with > , < operations.However, according to your answers it is imposible bacuase we can create and store only one type on bst and compare them , Am I right ?

Comment: For instace, I developed a genericLinkedList which takes Any type and store them and I can apply any function on that linkledlist. Now, I want to that situation for BST.For example, I want to store Any type on BST with (String,Int,Char). To solve this situation , Can I develop another method to compare them or someting else ?

Comment: A BST needs to have a type. You can create a BST with `String` and `Int`, whose `A` type will be `Any` (since it's the lower supertype of the two). Hence, if you have a `BST[Any]`, when you try to insert an element, `A` will be `Any`, `B` (the type of the new element) will be `>: Any` (i.e. `Any`), therefore you need an `Ordering[Any]` in order to compare the new element with the ones in the tree. If you can provide such `Ordering`, then you're good to go.

Comment: According to your codes, I can create BST[Any] with these **var bst = new Brach(2,Brach("x",Empty,Empty),Empty) ** am I right ? After that , when I want to insert to it Any value as **bst.add(2)** , the error occuors like **No implict ordering defined for Any** . In this sitution A will be Any that's okey.However,coming data is Int and when I change codes like (implicit ord: Ordering[Any]) that I cannot  solve error.

Comment: That's a limitation of the type system. The type `BST[T]` has an homogeneous type, hence when adding any element to a `BST[Any]`, the static type of such element will be `Any`, regardless of its dynamic type (`Int` in case of `2`). You can "cheat" and define an `Ordering[Any]` that supports `Int`, `String` and the types you need (by pattern matching, for instance), and fails at runtime for any other types. This is not type safe, but as long as you don't try to add any unsupported type you'll be fine.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella again thanks for your answers , When I fix it , I will share my opinion and codes here. Again thanks for you shareing your time with my issue.